# Full Calendar upgrade to 6.1.8 version in angular project 15

Tags: html, fullcalendar, angular15, angular-upgrade, fullcalendar-6

I have recently upgraded my project from Angular14 to Angular15 version15.2.9. Accordingly I upgraded the FullCalendar packages to 6.1.8 for compatability. Everything is working fine except that the time-slot that used to show earlier in the UI does not come anymore. Could someone please help highlight the issue. Attaching screenshot hereby.

Before upgrade:
[image]

After Upgrade:
[image]

Please help with this issue. Thanks.

I tried to debug the issue and I understand that it is coming from @fullcalendar/timegrid. Could not find anything else.

Comment: We cannot fix pictures a alone. You will need to provide a [mre] of the issue before anyone can help you. See also [ask]. If you believe it's an internal fullcalendar issue though, you would be better to raise a bug via their Github site. You need to ensure it's not the result of something in your own code though, before you do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.